# Vundle NeoVim как сделать php автодополнение?

Tags: linux, vim

Мне нужно для php поставить автодополнение. Выбрал m2mdas/phpcomplete-extended, при попытке установки через Vundle, как сказано в инструкции получаю ошибку: `Vimproc is a requirement for phpcomplete-extended plugin`. Как такое решить? Или можете посоветовать другой плагин? Заранее спасибо

Comment: как я понимаю он у вас просто просит поставить `vimproc` так как плагин не работает без него. Просто установите и все должно заработать

Comment: В том то и дело, что vimproc устанавливается перед phpcomplete